# Is the iOS Team Provisioning Profile compatible with the development aps-environment?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am trying to confirm that an ipa is ready for development Apple push notifications.

I know it's possible to break development aps-environment push notifications if signing with a distribution (production) provisioning profile, but what about the iOS Team Provisioning Profile?

Can I sign the app with this and still expect development aps-environment push notifications to work?

Here are the relevant excerpts from ipa's embedded.mobileprovision:

```
<key>Entitlements</key>
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>TEAMIDHERE.*</string>       
    </array>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>TEAMIDHERE.com.myapp.dev</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>TEAMIDHERE</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
<key>ExpirationDate</key>
<date>2018-07-31T22:07:59Z</date>
<key>Name</key>
<string>iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.myapp.dev</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can sign with the mentioned provisioning profile and expect push notification to work. 
But you must know that only provisioning profile does not contribute to apple push notification. You should also deploy the development push certificate to the server or service from where push notification will be sent to user.